# how to create this architect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a matrix like this

```
              User                                   trial                      free
package1      fullaccess                             limited access             very limited access
              partial access to downloads            previews                   expiration

package2      full access                            n/a                        n/a
              full access to assets
```

how would I create a schema for this scenario

Comment: What? This makes no sense. What are you asking about? Some context would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be best served by having a table for permissions:

```
Permission (PermissionID varchar)
```

(Containing such things as "Full Access", "Partial", etc) which would be a list of available permissions.

Then create packages: I would probably combine the User+Package as just packages

```
Package (PackageID int, PackageName varchar)
```

Finally populate your join table:

```
PackagePermissions (PackageID int, PermissionID varchar)
```

Giving your users a PackageID, you can query across the tables into the granted permissions.

```
select PermissionID
from User
inner join Package 
  on User.PackageID = Package.PackageID
inner join PackagePermission
  on Package.PackageID = PackagePermission.PacakgeID
```

This gives you the ability to alter the packages over time, add packages and add new permissions easily, all the while keeping the administration of your users to a minimum.